How to trigger reading NFC tags from screens
I'm trying to write code so my android app could read/write NFC tags from a screen. I use Kotlin and Jetpack Compose. I have one MainActivity.kt and two screens: HomeScreen.kt and NFCReader.kt. A button on HomeScreen.kt will open NFCReader.kt and a button on NFCReader.kt will start the read/write process.
I have tried using DisposableEffect but for some reason, it keeps triggering the phone's default NFC scanner.
Below is my code for DisposableEffect. I checked the logcat after every run and I couldn't find the log so I believe the I might not implement the effect correctly? Please help, TIA.
@Composable
fun NFCReader(
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
) {
    val nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(activity)
    val activity = LocalContext.current.getActivity() as ComponentActivity
    val context = LocalContext.current

    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME) {
                Log.d("TAG_", "turn on NFC reader here")
                val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    activity, 0, Intent(activity, javaClass).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
                )
                val intentFilters = arrayOf<IntentFilter>(
                    IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED),
                    IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED),
                    IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)
                )
                nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(activity, pendingIntent, intentFilters, null)
            }
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE) {
                Log.d("TAG_", "turn off NFC reader")
                nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(activity)
            }
        }
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        val listener = Consumer<Intent> {
            // Do something
            Log.d("TAG_", "inside listener")
        }
        activity.addOnNewIntentListener(listener)
        onDispose {
            activity1.removeOnNewIntentListener(listener)
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    }
}


It would help if you provided some info about the Type (make and model) of the NFC Tag and what data you expect to be on the NFC Tag. You can use the NXP App TagInfo to read the whole Tag an save the data to a file and then add the contents of the file to the question (warning depending on the Tag Data you might want to censor some of the data)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
